# Get values from one table and put in another table

Tags: php

I need to take some values from one table and save them into anther table. 
Values from users(id, first_name, last_name) and cars(id, makers, model) into third table. I've tried something, but i always get error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

This is my code:

```
<?php
include "db_connection.php";
session_start();

$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id_user=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);

if(isset($_POST["btn"]))
{
    $maker=$_POST["maker"];
    $model=$_POST["model"];
    $year=$_POST["year"];
    $fuel=$_POST["fuel"];
    $power=$_POST["power"];


    $sql2="insert into models values (0,'$maker','$model','$year','$fuel','$power')";
    $query2=mysql_query($sql2);


    $query = ("SELECT id_user, f_name, l_name FROM users WHERE id_user=".$_SESSION['user']); 
    $result = mysql_query($query); 
    if(!$result) { die($query."<br />".mysql_error()); } 

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    { 
         $data[]=$row; 
    } 

     if (!mysql_select_db("car")) { die(mysql_error()); } 

     foreach($data as $row) 
     { 
         $query  = "INSERT INTO evidencija (id_k,ime,prezime,'$maker','$model') VALUES ('"; 
         $query .= mysql_real_escape_string($row['id_user'])."','"; 
         $query .= mysql_real_escape_string($row['f_name'])."','"; 
         $query .= mysql_real_escape_string($row['l_name'])."'"; 

         if(!mysql_query($query)) { die($query."<br />".mysql_error()); } 
      } 
}
include "header.php";
?>
```

Comment: I suggest you add the SQL tag too.

Comment: is your value for id_user in mysql a string or int?

Comment: @samke Shouldn't you change `id_user` to `id`?

Comment: value for id_user is int, @Ormoz it is my mistake here, but in the code that i test it was all id_user, f_name, l_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change $query to:

```
    $query  = "INSERT INTO evidencija (id_k,ime,prezime,maker,model) VALUES ('"; 
     $query .= mysql_real_escape_string($row['id_user'])."','"; 
     $query .= mysql_real_escape_string($row['f_name'])."','"; 
     $query .= mysql_real_escape_string($row['l_name'])."','"; 
     $query .= mysql_real_escape_string($maker)."','"; 
     $query .= mysql_real_escape_string($model)."')";
```

Comment: @samke I changed a bit, if the error persists, please type `echo $query;` and post it.